# Problem with tables in document

Tags: tables

i have problem with tables in my document. Tablica 1 and Tablica 2 sould be under "5. Opracowanie wyników pomiarów" and over \paragraph{1...} . Here is a code, copied from http://pastebin.com/BqEXbst1:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\textbf{EAIiB} & \thead{1.\\ 2. } & \thead{Rok: \\ II} & \thead{Grupa: \\ 2} & \thead{Zespół: \\ 5} \\ \hline
& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Temat: } Wahadło fizyczne.} & \thead{nr ćwiczenia: \\ 1} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\thead{Data oddania: \\ 25.11.2015r.}} & \thead{Ocena: \\ } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\section{Cel ćwiczenia}
Celem ćwiczenia było zapoznanie się z ruchem drgającym wahadła fizycznego i wyznaczenie momentu bezwładności  brył sztywnych przez pomiar okresu drgań wahadła oraz na podstawie wymiarów geometrycznych.

\section{Układ pomiarowy}
\begin{itemize}
\item Statyw na którym zawiesiliśmy bryłę sztywną.
\item Pręt i pierścień.
\item Metalowy przymiar milimetrowy
\item Suwmiarka.
\item Waga elektroniczna.
\item Sekundomierz.
\end{itemize}

\section{Wykonanie ćwiczenia}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Zmierzyliśmy masę pręta i pierścienia.
\item Wyznaczyliśmy rozmiary pierścienia i uzupełniliśmy tabelki.
\item Umieściliśmy kolejno pręt i pierścień na statywie, wprowadziliśmy go w ruch drgający o amplitudzie nie przekraczającej trzech stopni i zmierzyliśmy czas kilkudziesięciu drgań, dziesięciokrotnie potworzyliśmy pomiar zarówno dla pręta jak i pierścienia. Wyniki zanotowaliśmy w tabelkach.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Wyniki pomiarów}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Pomiar masy i długości}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pręt} \\ \hline
& wartość & niepewność \\ \hline
m[g] & 658 & 1 \\ \hline
l[mm] & 746 & 1 \\ \hline
b[mm] & 97 & 1 \\ \hline
a[mm] & 276 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pierścień} \\ \hline
& wartość & niepewność \\ \hline
m[g] & 1343 & 1 \\ \hline
$D_{w}$[mm] & 262 & 1 \\ \hline
$D_{z}[mm]$ & 290 & 1 \\ \hline
$R_{z}[mm]$ & 131 & 1 \\ \hline
 $R_{w}[mm]$ & 146 & 1 \\ \hline
e[mm] & 11 & 0,05 \\ \hline
a[mm] &135 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Pomiar okresu drań}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Pręt} \\ \hline
Lp. & \thead{Liczba\\ okresów k}
         & \thead{Czas t[s]\\ dla k okresów} & Okres $T_{i}[s]$ \\ \hline
1 & 30 & 39.32 & 1.310 \\ \hline
2 & 30 & 39.16 & 1.305 \\ \hline
3 & 30 & 39.57 & 1.319 \\ \hline
4 & 30 & 38.91 & 1.297 \\ \hline
5 & 30 & 39.39 & 1.312 \\ \hline
6 & 30 & 39.16 & 1.304 \\ \hline
7 & 30 & 40.02 & 1.334 \\ \hline
8 & 30 & 39.27 & 1.309 \\ \hline
9 & 30 & 38.97 & 1.299 \\ \hline
10 & 30 & 39.44 & 1.314 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Wartość średnia okresu $1.3103$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Niepewność  $u(t): 3.38 * 10^{-3}$} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Pierścień} \\ \hline
Lp. & \thead{Liczba\\ okresów k}
         & \thead{Czas t[s]\\ dla k okresów} & Okres $T_{i}[s]$ \\ \hline
1 & 30 & 30.68 & 1.023 \\ \hline
2 & 30 & 30.75 & 1.025 \\ \hline
3 & 30 & 30.87 & 1.029 \\ \hline
4 & 40 & 40.93 & 1.023 \\ \hline
5 & 40 & 40.81 & 1.020 \\ \hline
6 & 30 & 30.52 & 1.017 \\ \hline
7 & 30 & 31.02 & 1.034 \\ \hline
8 & 40 & 41.11 & 1.028 \\ \hline
9 & 40 & 40.57 & 1.014 \\ \hline
10 & 30 & 30.65 & 1.022 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Wartość średnia okresu $T: 1.0235$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Niepewność  $u(t): 1.82 \cdot 10^{-3}$} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Opracowanie wyników pomiaru}


\paragraph{1. Moment bezwładności $I_{0}$ względem rzeczywistej osi obrotu}
\begin{equation}
T = 2 * \pi \sqrt{\frac{I_{0}}{mga}}
\end{equation}

Po przekształceniu:

\begin{equation}
I_{0} = \frac{m g a T^{2}}{4 * \pi^{2}}
\end{equation}

\noindent Gdzie:\newline
m - masa \newline
g - przyśpieszenie grawitacyjne \newline
a - odległość punktu zawieszenia od środka\newline
T - okres \newline

\paragraph{Dla pręta:}
\begin{equation*}
I_{0} = \frac{0,658 \cdot 9,81 \cdot 0,276 \cdot 1,717}{4 \cdot 3,14^{2}} = 7,76 \cdot 10^{-2} [kg \cdot m^2]
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Dla pierścienia: }

\begin{equation*}
I_{0} = \frac{1,343 * 9,81 * 0,135 * 1,048}{4 * 3,14^{2}} = 4,72 \cdot 10^{-2} [kg \cdot m^2]
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{2.Moment bezwładności $I_{s}$ korzystając z twierdzenia Steinera}

\begin{equation}
I_{s} = I_{0} - m \cdot a^{2}
\end{equation}

\paragraph{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s} = 7,76 \cdot 10^{-2} - 0,658 \cdot 0,276^{2} = 2,75 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s} = 4,73 \cdot 10^{-2} - 0,658 \cdot 0,135^{2} = 2,28 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{3. Moment bezwładności względem osi przechodzącej przez środek masy $I_{s}^{geom}$}
\paragraph{Dla pręta}
\begin{align*}
I_{s}^{geom} = \frac{1}{12} \cdot m \cdot l^2 = \frac{1}{12} \cdot 0,658 \cdot 0,746^{2} = 3,05 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{align*}

\paragraph{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s}^{geom}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot m \cdot (R_{z}^2 + R_{w}^2) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1,343 \cdot(0,145^2 + 0,131^2) = 2,58 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}


\paragraph{4. Obliczanie niepewności pomiarowych}

\begin{equation}
u(T) = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (T_{i} - \bar{T})^ 2 }{n(n-1)}}
\end{equation}

\paragraph{Dla pręta}

\begin{equation*}
u(T) = 3,38 \cdot 10^{-3}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
u(T) = 1,82 \cdot 10^{-3}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{5. Obliczanie niepewności złożonej momentu bezwładności $I_{0}$ oraz $I_{s}$}

\begin{equation}
u(I_{0}) = I_{0} \cdot \sqrt{\left(2\cdot \frac{u(T)}{T}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{u(m)}{m}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{u(a)}{a}\right)^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u(I_{s}) = \sqrt{[u(I_{0})]^2 + [a^2 \cdot u(m)]^2 + [-2\cdot a \cdot m \cdot u(m)]^2}
\end{equation}


\paragraph{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
u(I_{0}) = 4,405 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
u(I_{s}) = 5,76 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{equation*}
\paragraph{Dla pierścienia}

\begin{equation*}
u(I_{0}) = 3,90 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
u(I_{s}) = 5.32 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{6.Obliczanie niepewności $u_{c}(I_{s}^{geom})$}
\begin{equation}
u(I_{s}^{geom}) = I_{s}^{geom} \cdot \sqrt{\left[\frac{u(m)}{m}\right]^2 + \left[2\frac{u(l)}{l}\right]^2}
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
u(I_{s}^{geom}) = 9,404 \cdot 10^{-5}
\end{equation*}
\paragraph{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
u(I_{s}^{geom}) = 2.63 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{equation*}
\paragraph{8. Porównywanie dokładności metod wyznaczania momentu bezwładności}
Wyniki $u(I_{s})$ oraz $u(I_{s}^{geom})$ są w dużym stopniu zbliżone.
\paragraph{8. Porównywanie dokładności metod wyznaczania momentu bezwładności}
\begin{equation}
z = \frac{|I_{s} - I_{s}^{geom}|}{\sqrt{u^2(I_{s}) + u^2(I_{s}^{geom})}}
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
z = 0,5219
\end{equation*}
\paragraph{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
z = 0,51639
\end{equation*}


\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Wyniki obliczeń momentów bezwładności dla pręta}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
& \thead{$I_{0}$ wyznaczone \\ z okresu drań $[kg m^2]$ } & \thead{$I_{s}$ wyznaczone \\ z twierdzenia Steinera $[kg m^{2}]$ } & \thead{$I_{s}$ wyznaczone \\ z pomiarów geometrycznych $[kg m^2]$} \\ \hline
Wartość & $7,76 \cdot 10^{-2}$& $2,75 \cdot 10^{-2}$ & $3,05 \cdot 10^{-2}$\\ \hline
Niepewność & $4,405 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & $5,76 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & $9,404 \cdot 10^{-5}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Wyniki obliczeń momentów bezwładności dla pierścienia}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
& \thead{$I_{0}$ wyznaczone \\ z okresu drań $[kg m^2]$ } & \thead{$I_{s}$ wyznaczone \\ z twierdzenia Steinera $[kg m^{2}]$ } & \thead{$I_{s}$ wyznaczone \\ z pomiarów geometrycznych $[kg m^2]$} \\ \hline
Wartość & $4,72 \cdot 10^{-4}$& $2,28 \cdot 10^{-2}$ & $2,58 \cdot 10^{-2}$ \\ \hline
Niepewność & $5,76 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & $5,32 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & $2,63 \cdot 10^{-4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\paragraph{9. Wnioski}

Wartości momentów bezwładności uzyskano za pomocą dwóch metod:
- pomiaru okresu drgań wahadła fizycznego, a następnie obliczenia momentu z odpowiedniego wzoru
- zmierzenia masy i wymiarów, a następnie obliczenia momentu ze wzoru.
Otrzymane wyniki  są porównywalne dla pomiarów otrzymanych na oba sposoby, jednak pomiary wykonywane pierwszą metodą są obarczone dodatkowo błędem systematycznym wynikającym z tłumienia drgań


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please load your code here, It should be part of your question!

Comment: And your code is far from Minimal Working Example. I'm curious, how the tables should be after paragraph 5, if you put them till before paragraph 9? What is the problem?

Comment: Your solutions might lie with [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and/or [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Comment: I said tablica 1 and tablica 2, i put till before paragraph 9 tablica 3 and tablica 4. These sould be there. I tryied every letter from "!htbp" and nothing works

Comment: Tablica 1 and tablica 2 should be between 4 and 5 section. Between "4. Wyniki pomiarów" and "5.Opracowanie wyników pomiaru"

Comment: The _only_ reason to put a tabular in a table environment is to allow latex to move it to help with page breaking. That is why the \caption is there so that you can refer to it from the text body. If you don't want the table to move don't use `table` just use `tabular` (or use the float package and `\begin{table}[H]` which makes the table a non-float.

Comment: @Hadson - There's a conflict between what's stated in the body of the posting and a subsequent comment about where exactly tables 1 and 2 should be placed. Please edit/strike the inapplicable requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables 1 and 2 basically cannot fit at the bottom of the first page, and hence they must "float" to the next available space, which is on the following page. The only remedy -- other than to shorten the material on the first page -- is to insert an explicit `\clearpage` *before* the start of the fourth section.

Some further comments -- strictly about the LaTeX code, as I don't know Polish and hence can't comment on the *content* of the document:

- Use `\paragraph` for numbered paragraph-style headers, and `\paragraph*` for unnumbered paragraph-style headers. You can issue the instruction `\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}` in the preamble to reformat the way the paragraph numbers are shown.
- Don't type `[kgm^2]` in math italics. Instead, I suggest you load the `siunitx` package and write `\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}`. That way, you'll get the units typeset with upright letters, which is pretty much the international norm these days. Same goes for instances of `[mm]` and `[g]`, which you should write as `\si{\milli\meter}` and `\si{\gram}`, respectively.
- Encase commas that serve as decimal markers in curly braces, i.e., write them as `{,}` to keep TeX from interpreting the commas as punctuation marks.
- The tabular environments in Tables 2, 3, and 4 are much wider than the textblock. I suggest you use `tabularx` environments and a centered form of the `X` column type -- and let LaTeX do the calculations to make the tables fit.
- For consecutive numbered or unnumbered equations, don't use separate `equation` or `equation*` environments; instead, use `gather` and `gather*` environments in order to get better (viz., tighter) vertical spacing.
- Use `itemize` and `tabular` environments, as needed, to organize some of the material more formally. (See the code below.)
- Encase the string `geom` that occurs repeatedly in superscript in `\mathit` directives, so that LaTeX doesn't interpret and space the string `geom` as four separate variables named `g`, `e`, `o`, and `m`, respectively.
- Some of the numbers with exponents look awfully cramped in the tables, i.e., the exponents come very close to touching the horizontal lines. In the code below, I suggest throwing in judiciously placed `\mathstrut` directives to create a bit more "breathing space" for the numbers.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}  % "times" is obsolete
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
%%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,
              justification=justified,
              singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\textbf{EAIiB} & \thead{1.\\ 2. } & \thead{Rok: \\ II} & \thead{Grupa: \\ 2} & \thead{Zespół: \\ 5} \\ \hline
& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Temat: } Wahadło fizyczne.} & \thead{nr ćwiczenia: \\ 1} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\thead{Data oddania: \\ 25.11.2015r.}} & \thead{Ocena: \\ } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Cel ćwiczenia}
Celem ćwiczenia było zapoznanie się z ruchem drgającym wahadła fizycznego i wyznaczenie momentu bezwładności  brył sztywnych przez pomiar okresu drgań wahadła oraz na podstawie wymiarów geometrycznych.

\section{Układ pomiarowy}
\begin{itemize}
\item Statyw na którym zawiesiliśmy bryłę sztywną.
\item Pręt i pierścień.
\item Metalowy przymiar milimetrowy
\item Suwmiarka.
\item Waga elektroniczna.
\item Sekundomierz.
\end{itemize}

\section{Wykonanie ćwiczenia}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Zmierzyliśmy masę pręta i pierścienia.
\item Wyznaczyliśmy rozmiary pierścienia i uzupełniliśmy tabelki.
\item Umieściliśmy kolejno pręt i pierścień na statywie, wprowadziliśmy go w ruch drgający o amplitudzie nie przekraczającej trzech stopni i zmierzyliśmy czas kilkudziesięciu drgań, dziesięciokrotnie potworzyliśmy pomiar zarówno dla pręta jak i pierścienia. Wyniki zanotowaliśmy w tabelkach.
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage  % force a page break    
\section{Wyniki pomiarów}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Pomiar masy i długości}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pręt} \\ \hline
& wartość & niepewność \\ \hline
m[\si{\gram}] & 658 & 1 \\ \hline
l[\si{\milli\meter}] & 746 & 1 \\ \hline
b[\si{\milli\meter}] & 97 & 1 \\ \hline
a[\si{\milli\meter}] & 276 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pierścień} \\ \hline
& wartość & niepewność \\ \hline
m[\si{\gram}] & 1343 & 1 \\ \hline
$D_{w}$[\si{\milli\meter}] & 262 & 1 \\ \hline
$D_{z}[\si{\milli\meter}]$ & 290 & 1 \\ \hline
$R_{z}[\si{\milli\meter}]$ & 131 & 1 \\ \hline
$R_{w}[\si{\milli\meter}]$ & 146 & 1 \\ \hline
e[\si{\milli\meter}] & 11 & 0{,}05 \\ \hline
a[\si{\milli\meter}] &135 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % reduce amount of intercolumn whitespace
\caption{Pomiar okresu drań}
\begin{tabularx}{0.475\textwidth}[t]{|l|C|C|C|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Pręt} \\ \hline
Lp. & Liczba okresów k
    & Czas t[s] dla k okresów 
    & Okres $T_{i}[s]$ \\ \hline
1 & 30 & 39.32 & 1.310 \\ \hline
2 & 30 & 39.16 & 1.305 \\ \hline
3 & 30 & 39.57 & 1.319 \\ \hline
4 & 30 & 38.91 & 1.297 \\ \hline
5 & 30 & 39.39 & 1.312 \\ \hline
6 & 30 & 39.16 & 1.304 \\ \hline
7 & 30 & 40.02 & 1.334 \\ \hline
8 & 30 & 39.27 & 1.309 \\ \hline
9 & 30 & 38.97 & 1.299 \\ \hline
10 & 30 & 39.44 & 1.314 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Wartość średnia okresu $1.3103$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Niepewność  $u(t): 3.38 \cdot 10^{-3^{\mathstrut}}$} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabularx}{0.475\textwidth}[t]{|l|C|C|C|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Pierścień} \\ \hline
Lp. & Liczba okresów k
    & Czas t[s] dla k okresów 
    & Okres $T_{i}[s]$ \\ \hline
1 & 30 & 30.68 & 1.023 \\ \hline
2 & 30 & 30.75 & 1.025 \\ \hline
3 & 30 & 30.87 & 1.029 \\ \hline
4 & 40 & 40.93 & 1.023 \\ \hline
5 & 40 & 40.81 & 1.020 \\ \hline
6 & 30 & 30.52 & 1.017 \\ \hline
7 & 30 & 31.02 & 1.034 \\ \hline
8 & 40 & 41.11 & 1.028 \\ \hline
9 & 40 & 40.57 & 1.014 \\ \hline
10 & 30 & 30.65 & 1.022 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Wartość średnia okresu $T: 1.0235$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Niepewność  $u(t): 1.82 \cdot 10^{-3^{\mathstrut}}$} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\section{Opracowanie wyników pomiaru}

\paragraph{Moment bezwładności $I_{0}$ względem rzeczywistej osi obrotu}
\begin{equation}
T = 2 \cdot \pi \sqrt{\frac{I_{0}}{mga}}
\end{equation}

Po przekształceniu:
\begin{equation}
I_{0} = \frac{m g a T^{2}}{4 \cdot \pi^{2}}
\end{equation}

\noindent 
Gdzie:\newline
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}l}
m & masa \\
g & przyśpieszenie grawitacyjne \\
a & odległość punktu zawieszenia od środka \\
T & okres \\
\end{tabular}

\paragraph*{Dla pręta:}
\begin{equation*}
I_{0} = \frac{0{,}658 \cdot 9{,}81 \cdot 0{,}276 \cdot 1{,}717}{4 \cdot 3{,}14^{2}} = 7{,}76 \cdot 10^{-2} [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}]
\end{equation*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia: }

\begin{equation*}
I_{0} = \frac{1{,}343 \cdot 9{,}81 \cdot 0{,}135 \cdot 1{,}048}{4 \cdot 3{,}14^{2}} = 4{,}72 \cdot 10^{-2} [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}]
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Moment bezwładności $I_{s}$ korzystając z twierdzenia Steinera}

\begin{equation}
I_{s} = I_{0} - m \cdot a^{2}
\end{equation}

\paragraph*{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s} = 7{,}76 \cdot 10^{-2} - 0{,}658 \cdot 0{,}276^{2} = 2{,}75 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s} = 4{,}73 \cdot 10^{-2} - 0{,}658 \cdot 0{,}135^{2} = 2{,}28 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Moment bezwładności względem osi przechodzącej przez środek masy $I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}}$}

\paragraph*{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}} = \frac{1}{12} \cdot m \cdot l^2 = \frac{1}{12} \cdot 0{,}658 \cdot 0{,}746^{2} = 3{,}05 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot m \cdot (R_{z}^2 + R_{w}^2) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1{,}343 \cdot(0{,}145^2 + 0{,}131^2) = 2{,}58 \cdot 10^{-2}
\end{equation*}


\paragraph{Obliczanie niepewności pomiarowych}

\begin{equation}
u(T) = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (T_{i} - \bar{T})^ 2 }{n(n-1)}}
\end{equation}

\paragraph*{Dla pręta}    
\begin{equation*}
u(T) = 3{,}38 \cdot 10^{-3}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
u(T) = 1{,}82 \cdot 10^{-3}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Obliczanie niepewności złożonej momentu bezwładności $I_{0}$ oraz $I_{s}$}

\begin{gather}
u(I_{0}) = I_{0} \cdot \sqrt{\left(2\cdot \frac{u(T)}{T}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{u(m)}{m}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{u(a)}{a}\right)^2}\\
u(I_{s}) = \sqrt{[u(I_{0})]^2 + [a^2 \cdot u(m)]^2 + [-2\cdot a \cdot m \cdot u(m)]^2}
\end{gather}


\paragraph*{Dla pręta}
\begin{gather*}
u(I_{0}) = 4{,}405 \cdot 10^{-4}\\
u(I_{s}) = 5{,}76 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{gather*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{gather*}
u(I_{0}) = 3{,}90 \cdot 10^{-4}\\
u(I_{s}) = 5{,}32 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{gather*}

\paragraph{Obliczanie niepewności $u_{c}(I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}})$}
\begin{equation}
u(I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}}) = I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}} \cdot \sqrt{\left[\frac{u(m)}{m}\right]^2 + \left[2\frac{u(l)}{l}\right]^2}
\end{equation}

\paragraph*{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
u(I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}}) = 9{,}404 \cdot 10^{-5}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
u(I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}}) = 2{,}63 \cdot 10^{-4}
\end{equation*}

\paragraph{Porównywanie dokładności metod wyznaczania momentu bezwładności}
Wyniki $u(I_{s})$ oraz $u(I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}})$ są w dużym stopniu zbliżone.

\paragraph{Porównywanie dokładności metod wyznaczania momentu bezwładności}
\begin{equation}
z = \frac{|I_{s} - I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}}|}{\sqrt{u^2(I_{s}) + u^2(I_{s}^{\mathit{geom}})}}
\end{equation}

\paragraph*{Dla pręta}
\begin{equation*}
z = 0{,}5219
\end{equation*}

\paragraph*{Dla pierścienia}
\begin{equation*}
z = 0{,}51639
\end{equation*}


\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Wyniki obliczeń momentów bezwładności dla pręta}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|C|C|C|} \hline
& $I_{0}$ wyznaczone z okresu drań [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}]  
& $I_{s}$ wyznaczone z twierdzenia Steinera [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}]  
& $I_{s}$ wyznaczone z pomiarów geometrycznych [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}] \\ \hline
Wartość & $7{,}76 \cdot 10^{-2^{\mathstrut}}$& $2{,}75 \cdot 10^{-2}$ & $3{,}05 \cdot 10^{-2}$\\ \hline
Niepewność & $4{,}405 \cdot 10^{-4^{\mathstrut}}$ & $5{,}76 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & $9{,}404 \cdot 10^{-5}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Wyniki obliczeń momentów bezwładności dla pierścienia}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|C|C|C|} \hline
& $I_{0}$ wyznaczone z okresu drań [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}]  
& $I_{s}$ wyznaczone z twierdzenia Steinera [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}]  
& $I_{s}$ wyznaczone z pomiarów geometrycznych [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}] \\ \hline
Wartość & $4{,}72 \cdot 10^{-4^{\mathstrut}}$& $2{,}28 \cdot 10^{-2}$ & $2{,}58 \cdot 10^{-2}$ \\ \hline
Niepewność & $5{,}76 \cdot 10^{-4^{\mathstrut}}$ & $5{,}32 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & $2{,}63 \cdot 10^{-4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\paragraph{Wnioski}

Wartości momentów bezwładności uzyskano za pomocą dwóch metod:
\begin{itemize}
\item pomiaru okresu drgań wahadła fizycznego, a następnie obliczenia momentu z odpowiedniego wzoru
\item zmierzenia masy i wymiarów, a następnie obliczenia momentu ze wzoru.
\end{itemize}
Otrzymane wyniki  są porównywalne dla pomiarów otrzymanych na oba sposoby, jednak pomiary wykonywane pierwszą metodą są obarczone dodatkowo błędem systematycznym wynikającym z tłumienia drgań


\end{document}
```